# Export AWS credentials from Go program (SDK v2, SSO)

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go

I have a Go program which uses shared SSO authentication. The program itself works fine, but I need to start a nested program from it (`docker`), and this program needs the AWS credentials from the main program.

I use AWS SDK v2.

How can I export my current credentials as environment variables?

I understand that I can use `assumeRole`, like this:

```
    credentials, err := ssoClient.GetRoleCredentials(context.TODO(), &sso.GetRoleCredentialsInput{
        AccountId:   aws.String(accountID),
        RoleName:    aws.String(roleName),
    })
```

but that would be wrong, because I have no role to assume; I just want to use my current user.

Another possible solution could be parsing `~/.aws/cli/cache/*.json` manually, but this solutions looks too low level and hacky (but probably it is the only one, at least I didn't manage to find anything better).

Comment: [This change](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/commit/e8777b6237dace715062a845d7bb90e44870fc37) which brought in support for the SSO to SDK v2, says: «The provider must find a valid non-expired access token for the AWS SSO user portal URL in `~/.aws/sso/cache`.» Looking at [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/b7d8e15425d2f86a0596e8d7db2e33bf382a21dd/credentials/ssocreds/provider.go#L78), I see that the token obtained from the SSO cache gets decoded into plain `aws.Credentials`, so seems like you can just export them as is.

Comment: @kostix: Yes, I saw this code, but looks somehow strange to me. The problem is, that in order to get the credentials this way, you need a lot of things that you actually don't have (role etc). It is not possible to pass `nil` into this function, though internally it can handle nil values properly. There should be some better way, I think...

Comment: Problem is,  those sso creds are only good for a limited time.   What sdk is in the docker?  Can't you just share ~/.aws and expose AWS env vars for PROFILE and REGION, if set?

Comment: @DanielFarrell: Yes, it is fine, that they are limited; my docker builds need much less time. Anyway, I found a solution and it was much more simple than I thought. I will post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, and it is much simpler than I expected.

One can take credentials directly in the config struct:

```
    cfg, err := awsconfig.LoadDefaultConfig(
        context.TODO(),
        awsconfig.WithSharedConfigProfile(profile))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    cred, err := cfg.Credentials.Retrieve(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\"%s\"\n", cred.AccessKeyID)
    fmt.Printf("export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\"%s\"\n", cred.SecretAccessKey)
    fmt.Printf("export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\"%s\"\n", cred.SessionToken)
```